# Animating X and Y parameters of Canvas Shape

Tags: jquery, animation, canvas

I'm really new to Canvas, and I'm currently using the oCanvas plugin in order to achieve an effect similar to the one here: http://www.meetgraham.com.au/view-graham

So far, it's going well. However, I need to animate the ellipse to grow bigger and move to the mouse position when the canvas is first clicked. I've got the ellipse growing as expected by using jQuery `.animate();` to animate the `radius` of the shape. However, it doesn't seem to work with the `x` and `y` parameters - does anyone know how I can animate those to move to the current mouse position?

Here's my code:

```
var ellipseStroke = canvas.display.ellipse({
x: 10, 
y: 10,
radius: 50,
stroke: "10px #fff"
});
var ellipse = canvas.display.ellipse({
x: 10,
y: 10,
radius: 50,
fill: "white",
composition:"destination-atop"
});

// Add circle to the canvas
canvas.addChild(ellipseStroke);
canvas.addChild(ellipse);

//Define the Seymour variable to determine whether the user has clicked the canvas or not.
var seymour = false;
$('#canvas').click(function(){
ellipse.animate({
        radius: 150,
        x: 200,
        y: 200,
    },1000);
    ellipseStroke.animate({
        radius: 150,
        x: 200,
        y: 200,
    },1000);
    seymour = true;
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue.

Turns out, I was using the awesome **oCanvas** library, and it's very easy to animate numerical-only properties using that.

```
//Define the Seymour variable to determine whether the user has clicked the canvas or not.
var seymour = false;
canvas.bind("click tap",function(){
    ellipse.animate({
    y: canvas.mouse.y,
    x: canvas.mouse.x,
    radius: 150
}, {
    easing: "ease-in-out-cubic"
});
ellipseStroke.animate({
    y: canvas.mouse.y,
    x: canvas.mouse.x,
    radius: 150
}, {
    easing: "ease-in-out-cubic",
    callback:function(){
        seymour = true;
    }
});
$('#canvas').click(function(){
    $('#canvas-sleeve').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
});
```